# Is "feeble" not "Unfriendly or unkind"?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags, unfriendly-or-unkind

I flagged a comment a couple of days ago that I felt met the "unfriendly or unkind" criteria, but it has been declined. The comment had useful information in it, but then finished with:

> so much easier and straight-forward than your current feeble attempt, which is likely to break rather easily

Regardless of the fact that the question poster was a new contributor, it seems to me that the use of the word "feeble" (synonyms: weak, ineffective, inadequate, poor, inept, futile, useless) in the comment is rude and condescending, which should fit the definition of "unfriendly and unkind".

Can someone please explain why this flag was declined?

As requested, the entire comment is:

> Hey, and welcome to StackOverflow. I'd advice against using regular expressions to deal with X/HTML parsing as it's known to be a convoluted process. Instead, why not use an actual HTML parser like DOMDocument, which understands how to properly parse HTML and provides you with a sane API to work with the DOM. This will likely make your attempt to handle HTML so much easier and straight-forward than your current feeble attempt, which is likely to break rather easily.

Comment: I regularly make feeble attempts to code things. Yesterday, I made a feeble attempt to write some JavaScript code. If you looked at it, and you called it "feeble" while giving me advice on how to improve it, I would not think that was rude. I would think that was helpful. Calling *code* feeble is not a personal attack.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not disagreeing with the helpful part. I just feel there are plenty of other ways to say that your effort wasn't very good without using what I consider offensive language.

Comment: I edited out the word "feeble" (which is likely what I would have done were it me who processed your flag originally). I think that strikes a reasonable balance that addresses your concerns about the language without losing the message. You do know, of course, that there's no way anyone can go back and change the disposition of a flag, so this is really just a matter of debating whether or not we think the comment was "unfriendly or unkind".

Comment: @CodyGray absolutely - I don't care about the declined flag itself just the reasoning behind it - and I am more than happy with that response. If you indicate you've seen this comment I'll delete the thread.

Comment: I have seen it. Please don't take my disagreement regarding what is unfriendly as pressuring you into deleting the thread. If you want to have the discussion on Meta, you are fully entitled to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray not at all. I fully expect people to disagree with things said on meta, I often do myself. I'm only thinking that there isn't much use to anyone else in this thread.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that the key difference here is nuanced in who the remark is meant for.

It is not the case that the commentator is calling someone feeble or feeble-minded.  They are calling the *code* feeble.  And, given that [regex is pretty brittle when dealing with HTML anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1079354), the comment is at least on-stream.

I won't necessarily disagree that the message could've been delivered a bit nicer. But, it's not the case that it's apparently rude or condescending.

Comment: Especially when the full comment turns out to be rather helpful, even if the phrasing could be massively improved